# Using Sort vs SortBy

Tags: sorting

So I have two lists, A and B.  I put them into `lists = {A,B}`I want to sort A such that `Im[#1]<Im[#2]&` which I can do fine through `Sort[]` .The problem is that I want to keep the order the same so that A[[1]] stays with B[[1]] and A[[n]] stays with B[[n]].  When I try `SortBy[lists\[Transpose],Im]` it does not sort in the same order as  the sort function does, but it keeps the A[[n]] with the B[[n]]

EDIT::Example  (I still can't figure out how to nicely format)

```
A={0.651301, 0.671298, -0.000107956 + 0.735512 I,  9.93631*10^-6 + 0.764605 I, 0.965926,     0.97048, 0.0344992 + 1.4214 I,  0.0028631 + 1.4505 I, -0.0626803 + 1.78014 I, -0.12443 + 1.98252 I,  0.167724 + 2.24691 I}



B={{-2.44558*10^-6 - 1.01111*10^-6 I, -5.65309*10^-6 + 0.000018407 I, 
  0.000141659 + 0.0000359384 I, 
  0.000116428 - 0.000796561 I, -0.00506101 - 0.000580627 I, 
  0.000125772 + 0.0163992 I, 0.0817805 + 9.02056*10^-16 I, 
  0.000126129 + 0.0177878 I, 0.00153561 - 0.000581627 I, 
  0.000126597 + 0.000582107 I, -9.00118*10^-7 - 
   0.0000107003 I, -0.0000285126 - 0.0000117884 I, -0.0000659084 + 
   0.000214604 I, 0.00165158 + 0.000419 I, 
  0.00135741 - 0.00928697 I, -0.0590055 - 0.00676943 I, 
  0.00146635 + 0.191195 I, 0.953465 + 0. I, 0.00147052 + 0.207385 I, 
  0.0179034 - 0.00678109 I, 
  0.00147597 + 0.00678669 I, -0.0000104943 - 
   0.000124753 I}, {0.000116916 - 0.000811922 I, -0.00509776 - 
   0.000578293 I, 0.000129979 + 0.0163556 I, 
  0.079143 - 1.63203*10^-14 I, 0.000130143 + 0.0177879 I, 
  0.00147459 - 0.000580172 I, 
  0.00013056 + 0.00059606 I, -2.43588*10^-6 - 0.0000107979 I, 
  4.37224*10^-6 + 9.43651*10^-6 I, -3.88572*10^-7 + 7.61008*10^-9 I, 
  7.14058*10^-8 + 9.11373*10^-8 I, 
  0.00140496 - 0.00975669 I, -0.0612586 - 0.00694921 I, 
  0.00156193 + 0.196542 I, 0.951044 + 0. I, 0.0015639 + 0.213753 I, 
  0.0177198 - 0.0069718 I, 
  0.00156891 + 0.00716271 I, -0.0000292714 - 0.000129756 I, 
  0.0000525402 + 0.000113396 I, -4.66939*10^-6 + 9.14486*10^-8 I, 
  8.58068*10^-7 + 1.09518*10^-6 I}, {-0.00335176 - 0.00246906 I, 
  0.000695327 + 0.0163725 I, -0.00001055 - 
   0.0718776 I, -0.000733202 + 0.0162968 I, 
  0.00326678 - 0.00242532 I, -0.000740926 + 0.000255124 I, 
  0.00011033 + 0.0000490118 I, -0.0000121133 - 0.0000148216 I, 
  2.39696*10^-8 + 2.36464*10^-6 I, 
  1.63148*10^-7 - 2.69095*10^-7 I, -3.15697*10^-8 + 1.27853*10^-8 I, 
  0.0325148 - 0.0441254 I, -0.215566 + 0.00912321 I, 
  0.94636 + 0. I, -0.214567 - 0.00968502 I, 
  0.0319261 + 0.0430159 I, -0.0033576 - 0.00975571 I, -0.000645516 + 
   0.00145253 I, 
  0.000195169 - 0.000159459 I, -0.0000311336 + 3.1102*10^-7 I, 
  3.54266*10^-6 + 2.14857*10^-6 I, -1.68274*10^-7 - 
   4.1568*10^-7 I}, {-1.79728*10^-7 - 
   3.0708*10^-7 I, -8.50791*10^-8 + 2.61365*10^-6 I, 
  0.0000132867 - 0.0000158544 I, -0.000117531 + 0.0000495126 I, 
  0.000766382 + 0.000269089 I, -0.00325494 - 0.0024853 I, 
  0.000752542 + 0.0162187 I, 
  8.95415*10^-7 - 0.0689027 I, -0.000751796 + 0.0162166 I, 
  0.0032569 - 0.00249056 I, -0.000776443 + 0.000265907 I, 
  4.20299*10^-6 - 2.46001*10^-6 I, -0.0000357732 - 1.16402*10^-6 I, 
  0.000217003 + 0.000181853 I, -0.000677703 - 
   0.00160864 I, -0.00368289 + 0.0104896 I, 
  0.0340159 - 0.0445509 I, -0.221987 + 0.010303 I, 
  0.943075 + 0. I, -0.221957 - 0.010287 I, 
  0.0340891 + 0.0445769 I, -0.00363963 - 
   0.0106272 I}, {-0.0000127475 + 0.0000447811 I, 
  0.000264418 + 0.0000598865 I, 
  0.000164152 - 0.0012308 I, -0.00570662 - 0.000548632 I, 
  0.000189568 + 0.0156506 I, 0.0523487 - 2.28983*10^-16 I, 
  0.000191336 + 0.0176777 I, 0.000560154 - 0.000551883 I, 
  0.000187274 + 0.000764703 I, -0.0000430526 - 5.84824*10^-6 I, 
  8.05585*10^-6 + 0.0000148798 I, -0.000220415 + 0.000774304 I, 
  0.00457202 + 0.00103549 I, 
  0.00283833 - 0.0212815 I, -0.0986724 - 0.00948632 I, 
  0.0032778 + 0.270612 I, 0.905154 + 0. I, 0.00330836 + 0.305662 I, 
  0.00968555 - 0.00954253 I, 
  0.00323813 + 0.0132224 I, -0.000744416 - 0.000101121 I, 
  0.000139292 + 0.000257285 I}, {0.000262801 + 0.0000592442 I, 
  0.000164475 - 0.00123486 I, -0.00571449 - 0.00054799 I, 
  0.000190521 + 0.015638 I, 0.0520548 - 1.61329*10^-16 I, 
  0.000192306 + 0.0176744 I, 0.000545908 - 0.000551356 I, 
  0.000188135 + 0.000766815 I, -0.0000438809 - 5.72083*10^-6 I, 
  8.14335*10^-6 + 0.0000150479 I, -1.6632*10^-6 + 4.54164*10^-7 I, 
  0.00456548 + 0.00102921 I, 
  0.00285732 - 0.0214524 I, -0.0992743 - 0.00951989 I, 
  0.0033098 + 0.27167 I, 0.904315 + 0. I, 0.00334081 + 0.307047 I, 
  0.00948372 - 0.00957837 I, 
  0.00326835 + 0.0133214 I, -0.000762316 - 0.0000993844 I, 
  0.000141469 + 0.000261419 I, -0.0000288938 + 
   7.88991*10^-6 I}, {0.00324399 + 0.0151276 I, 
  0.000797234 - 0.0328468 I, -0.00205405 + 0.0139652 I, 
  0.00309583 - 0.0034084 I, -0.00125203 + 0.000542748 I, 
  0.000308022 + 0.0000414382 I, -0.0000545185 - 0.0000426274 I, 
  4.65124*10^-6 + 0.0000121837 I, 
  4.78853*10^-7 - 2.32735*10^-6 I, -2.68691*10^-7 + 2.83621*10^-7 I, 
  6.02922*10^-8 - 1.38336*10^-8 I, -0.382907 + 0.0918831 I, 
  0.836255 + 0. I, -0.356603 - 0.0436393 I, 
  0.088636 + 0.076666 I, -0.014583 - 0.0315217 I, -0.000864141 + 
   0.00786298 I, 
  0.00105095 - 0.00141351 I, -0.000307133 + 0.000125871 I, 
  0.0000595133 + 0.0000107468 I, -7.38245*10^-6 - 6.66148*10^-6 I, 
  3.8922*10^-7 + 1.52555*10^-6 I}, {2.82086*10^-7 + 
   2.97789*10^-7 I, -4.59823*10^-7 - 
   2.41021*10^-6 I, -5.01508*10^-6 + 0.0000122796 I, 
  0.0000564073 - 0.0000412174 I, -0.000307185 + 0.000029994 I, 
  0.00120889 + 0.000596331 I, -0.00288513 - 0.00343464 I, 
  0.00114029 + 0.0135455 I, 
  0.0000642005 - 0.0325252 I, -0.0009149 + 0.0138614 I, 
  0.00312207 - 0.00369177 I, -7.71767*10^-6 + 7.33966*10^-6 I, 
  0.0000625579 - 0.0000120629 I, -0.000319098 - 0.000129588 I, 
  0.00107311 + 0.00146251 I, -0.000794541 - 
   0.00797456 I, -0.0154218 + 0.0314195 I, 
  0.089033 - 0.0750887 I, -0.351653 + 0.030302 I, 
  0.844524 + 0. I, -0.359961 - 0.0230451 I, 
  0.0960172 + 0.0808758 I}, {-0.000892536 - 0.0253483 I, 
  0.00398093 + 0.0167517 I, 
  0.00137243 - 0.00591337 I, -0.0015116 + 0.00179952 I, 
  0.000585214 - 0.000258793 I, -0.000165802 - 0.0000248498 I, 
  0.0000301279 + 0.0000234092 I, -2.58394*10^-6 - 
   7.57878*10^-6 I, -3.51243*10^-7 + 1.52852*10^-6 I, 
  2.06661*10^-7 - 1.94772*10^-7 I, -4.87722*10^-8 + 8.31709*10^-9 I, 
  0.808747 + 0. I, -0.538275 + 0.10806 I, 
  0.186895 + 0.0503687 I, -0.0556474 - 0.0501875 I, 
  0.00759005 + 0.0189387 I, 
  0.000977896 - 0.00525555 I, -0.000779761 + 0.000933787 I, 
  0.000244404 - 0.000073836 I, -0.0000483136 - 0.0000129077 I, 
  5.9747*10^-6 + 6.80398*10^-6 I, -2.10308*10^-7 - 
   1.5635*10^-6 I}, {-2.51454*10^-7 - 1.09646*10^-7 I, 
  8.24658*10^-7 + 1.17552*10^-6 I, -5.98381*10^-7 - 
   7.07371*10^-6 I, -0.0000140755 + 0.0000294825 I, 
  0.000112869 - 0.0000806044 I, -0.000523179 + 0.0000579476 I, 
  0.00169884 + 0.000648417 I, -0.00347909 - 0.00374662 I, 
  0.00369489 + 0.0120913 I, -0.00129613 - 0.020651 I, -0.00517517 + 
   0.0120722 I, 
  4.45129*10^-6 - 8.67954*10^-6 I, -0.0000435543 + 0.0000266477 I, 
  0.000252369 - 5.47974*10^-6 I, -0.00101494 - 0.00056519 I, 
  0.00260914 + 0.00418509 I, -0.000891151 - 0.018696 I, -0.0267954 + 
   0.0588452 I, 0.140712 - 0.115123 I, -0.437333 + 0.104194 I, 
  0.735762 + 0. I, -0.4169 - 0.210549 I}, {1.30427*10^-7 + 
   1.21266*10^-7 I, -2.01494*10^-7 - 
   8.56205*10^-7 I, -1.39899*10^-6 + 3.95881*10^-6 I, 
  0.0000142534 - 0.0000114838 I, -0.0000753911 + 9.27582*10^-6 I, 
  0.000259802 + 0.000101574 I, -0.000571574 - 0.000745225 I, 
  0.000756398 + 0.00272191 I, 
  0.00135245 - 0.0061366 I, -0.00737014 + 0.0139213 I, 
  0.00132698 - 0.0177768 I, -4.48592*10^-6 + 5.61005*10^-6 I, 
  0.0000338329 - 0.0000106751 I, -0.00016343 - 0.0000443834 I, 
  0.000504691 + 0.000538816 I, -0.000599442 - 
   0.0030045 I, -0.00330544 + 0.0107546 I, 
  0.028258 - 0.025227 I, -0.107208 + 0.0385957 I, 
  0.250884 + 0.035973 I, -0.582065 - 0.254641 I, 0.718994 + 0. I}}
```

Comment: An example, if you don't mind?

Comment: I just threw it in there.  Like I said, `Sort[]` gives me teh order I want in A, but the B doesnt sort with it.  `SortBy[]` does not sort A the way I want it to

Comment: Also, sorry for the mess of code, still trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: You can `hilight inline code like this` by enclosing the text with ` or multiple lines by preceeding each line with 4 spaces (hilight the code and click the "{}" tool in the editor does this for you)

Comment: Try `Ordering` in order to get the order of the `Sort` and then apply it to B.

Comment: I don't quite understand the Ordering command even through the documentation.  Would it be Sort[A], then `Sort[B,Ordering@A]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Ordering` to get the new ordering of `a` and then rearrange both `a` and `b` accordingly:

```
a = RandomComplex[1 + 1 I, {100, 1}];
b = RandomComplex[1 + 1 I, {100, 1}];

o = Ordering[a, All, Im[#1] < Im[#2] &];
sa = a[[o]];
sb = b[[o]];
```

Comment: Thank you.  thank you. thank you